# Smoothening masonry surface

Tags: masonry

Is there an appropriate grinder blade, or another tool, with which I can iron out masonry surfaces like this? Sort of like a masonry equivalent of a planer or a belt sander.

[image]

Comment: Are you concerned about the finish or texture being different than the original? As in swirl marks or different color from grinding...

Comment: just to make it as smooth as possible for painting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can purchase "masonry sanding disks" or sheets for common sanders. Just watch out for the dust.

Here the wall has a lot of irregularities.  Consider a chisel to get the bad stuff knocked down, then a professional skim coat of plaster over the top.

Comment: We call the tool a turbo wheel.  Definitely better looking to minimally get the big stuff off then smooth it out by applying something over the top.  But highly likely that over time (relatively long time), whatever is applied will start coming off and start to look horrible and a pain to properly repair and/or maintain. If you can do with out applying something by just smoothing things out, that would last longer and be more maintenance free; mostly just quick prep down the road and repainting.